# Stata does not appear to accept forward slashes in Stata 16

Tags: stata

Example from [here](https://www.stata.com/features/overview/structural-equation-modeling/#fitting).

```
webuse sem_sm2, clear

sem ///
(anomia67 pwless67 <- Alien67) /// measurement piece
(anomia71 pwless71 <- Alien71) /// measurement piece
(Alien67 <- SES) /// structural piece
(Alien71 <- Alien67 SES) /// structural piece
(SES -> educ occstat66), nolog //  measurement piece
```

What I get is somehow:

```
. sem ///
invalid use of '/'
r(198);

. 
. (anomia67 pwless67 <- Alien67) /// measurement piece
( is not a valid command name
r(199);

. 
. (anomia71 pwless71 <- Alien71) /// measurement piece
( is not a valid command name
r(199);

. 
. (Alien67 <- SES) /// structural piece
( is not a valid command name
r(199);

. 
. (Alien71 <- Alien67 SES) /// structural piece
( is not a valid command name
r(199);

. 
. (SES -> educ occstat66), nolog //  measurement piece
( is not a valid command name
r(199);
```

Could anyone tell me what is going on here? A colleague can run this in a different version. Did the syntax change?

Comment: I doubt that your colleague's using a different version is material here. They are presumably putting code in a do-file or program. There was no syntax change in this respect in Stata 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [[U] 16.1.2](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u16.pdf) in the manuals for basic explanation of comments.

> The /* */, //, and /// comment indicators can be used in do-files and
> ado-files only; you may not use them interactively. You can, however,
> use the ‘*’ *comment indicator interactively*.